# Cannot form URL in PHP correctly when concatenated with variable

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to concatenate a variable and a string to form a URL which will be used to form a JSON object. However, although I receive a valid JSON response (using Wordreference API) as the URL must not be formed properly where the variable is concatenated.

For example the response with the URL `http://api.wordreference.com/[APIKEY]/json/enfr/language`:

`{ "Error" : "NoTranslation", "Note" : "No translation was found for language\_\_.\nAucune traduction trouvée pour language\_\_.\n" }`

There should be a valid response it tells me the word does not exist even though it appears the url is formed correctly and the word is valid and if I enter the URL into a browser I get a valid response.

I think it has something to do with the characters at the end of `language\_\_.`, where the normal error response (eg, with random invalid word 'qwerty') is:

```
{
    "Error" : "NoTranslation", 
    "Note" : "No translation was found for qweryty.\nAucune traduction trouvée pour qweryty."
}
```

Where the character at the end is only `qweryty.\n`

The code I am using is:

```
$words = file("words.txt")[rand(0, 5449)];
$url = "http://api.wordreference.com/[APIKEY]/json/enfr/$words";
//I have also tried using $url = "http://api.wordreference.com/[APIKEY]/json/enfr/" . $words";
echo $url .  "<br/>";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
```

PHP output is:

```
 http://api.wordreference.com/5d422/json/enfr/language
{ "Error" : "NoTranslation", "Note" : "No translation was found for language\_\_.\nAucune traduction trouvée pour language\_\_." }
```

(The words.txt comes from http://dictionary-thesaurus.com/wordlists/Nouns%285,449%29.txt)

N.B. I do also have a valid api key, I have just subbed in [APIKEY] here for the question.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please clearly state what the problem is?

Comment: @lincb Where there should be a valid response it tells me the word does not exist even though it appears the url is formed correctly and the word is valid

Comment: Can you include the full PHP output, including the URL?

Comment: 'http://api.wordreference.com/5d422/json/enfr/language
{ "Error" : "NoTranslation", "Note" : "No translation was found for language\_\_.\nAucune traduction trouvée pour language\_\_." } '

Comment: It appears you are doing absolutely nothing to urlencode the values you concatenate to the string.  Can you give an example of what the actual URL that is used to make the request looks like? I am not familiar with the API bieng used, but does it really in essence expect a text file to be passed in the URL?  That would seem to be a very odd API implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quote: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file.asp Each array element contains a line from the file, with newline still attached.

You need to trim the newline from the end of the request.

```
$words = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', file("words.txt")[rand(0, 5449)]);
```

Comment: However if I try a URL in a browser (eg, http://api.wordreference.com/5d422/json/enfr/language) it works!

Comment: It just doesn't work with the request in the php code, through the browser though it's fine (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: Is it something to do with php's `file_get_contents()` making a different type of request that the api doesnt like?

Comment: Edited, I think i figured it out.